# Unicode in Traits Labels?

Tags: python, unicode, label, traits, canopy

I'd like to use some Unicode in the labels for Traits Items (so I can use some nice mathematical characters), but I'm getting an error message that says that labels have to be strings...is there any way around using only ASCII strings in Item Labels?

Comment: And the language is ... label! Oh, that's not a language...

Comment: Please post the relevant code and maybe also the exact error message.

Comment: Sorry, this is in Canopy Python..., but I think I got it figured out...I'll post what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was using plain ascii strings (or in some cases Trait Strings) as my labels, hence the messages about not being able to place Unicode characters in my labels (it'd have helped if the Canopy error message had suggested using Unicode strings :))

I 'fixed' the issue by specifying that my labels were Unicode strings like this:

```
KIcUnits = Unicode(u'MPa/√(m) ')
```

and then when I used it in my Item it displayed correctly without errors:

```
Item( name = 'KIcUnits', style = 'readonly', show_label = False),
```